# AngularJs - Linking js code within js directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very elaborate directive for an angularjs app I'm building. I would like to break the code to seperate JS files then include them into 1 JS directive file. For example rather than having all the code in one js file I would have:

```
myapp-directive-http-request.js
myapp-directive-init.js
myapp-directive-event.js
myapp-directive-function.js
```

Then myapp-directive.js would link to all the above files.

Pretty much I am looking at a similar function as include("FILEPATH") in PHP or as ng-include in the angularjs html view. Is it possible to do this javascript or angularjs within the directive section?

My directive code looks like:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive("myApp",['$http', function($http){

return{
            link: function(scope,element,attrs){ // normal variables rather than actual $scope, that is the scope data is passed into scope
                //all functions, init etc code is here

            },//return
            restrict:"A", //assign as attribute only ie <div my-modal> Content </div>
            replace:true,//replaces div with element, note if this is the case must all template must be wrapped within one root element. eg button is within ul otherwise get an error. 


            templateUrl:"partials/myapp/myapp.html",//template
            transclude:true, //incorporate additional data within
            scope:{
            } //If on this should mean the html input is not binded to custom directive
        }//return
}])
```

Comment: *"I have a very elaborate controller for an angularjs app I'm building"* - where is it?

Comment: sorry code and question updated

Answer (score 0):

Use any build system of your choice. Webpack, RequireJS, Browserify, JSPM - all of them are capable of that. `require('...')` function (ES2015-fashioned `System.import` in the case of JSPM) will do the work.

Loading the modules asynchronously (as opposed to building a bundle) is not recommended in this case because directive compilation process won't wait for them to be loaded.

```
myapp-directive-http-request.js
myapp-directive-init.js
myapp-directive-event.js
myapp-directive-function.js
```

doesn't look like a good split-up. A fat directive or controller is usually an indicator of poor design. Generally you may want to separate everything that's not related to DOM or scope to services and keep the directive intact. Making several directives from one may also be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks after doing some further reading around I thought this would be the case. Do you have link that explains how to inject multiple controllers to a directive?....I think may have to rehash my question